# Incorrect work of Spring scheduler on another server

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I have such a problem - I configured myself Spring scheduler in the spring mvc application.
I use the server tomcat 9. Locally it works for me as it should, i.e. It is called exactly after as many as I set in the parameters.
But on my server (the web server is also tomcat 9) start method "run" much more often and I don’t understand what the problem is. Maybe someone came across a similar one?

Spring Configs:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.learningEnglishWords" />

<context:annotation-config/>

<!--@Transaction annotation support -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="emailManager" class="com.learningEnglishWords.managers.EmailManager"  >
    <property name="dataDAO" ref="dataDao" />
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled  ref="emailManager" method="run" fixed-delay="900000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

My bean:

```
public class EmailManager {

public EmailManager() { }

public void run() {
  ......
}
```

Comment: What does *much more often* mean? How often does the method run? Can you post stacktraces? Are you sure the method itself is not being called directly from somewhere else?

Comment: logs: 2020-Feb-18 19:38:39 PM [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  com.learningEnglishWords.managers.EmailManager - method run...  2020-Feb-18 19:38:53 PM [pool-4-thread-1] INFO  com.learningEnglishWords.managers.EmailManager - method run...   2020-Feb-18 19:39:22 PM [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  com.learningEnglishWords.managers.EmailManager - method run...

Comment: It is problem not spring, it is problem java 8, open jdk... my code block run many times... static {
        EmailManager emailManager = new EmailManager();
        emailManager.run();
    }

Comment: How many server instances are running?